# HTTPS for socket.io via Cloudflare

Tags: node.js, sockets, ssl, socket.io, cloudflare

I have a chrome extension which uses an externel socket.io server to connect clients together.

During development I was able to connect to the server via `http://localhost:2087` just fine, but right now I need socket.io to work over HTTPS so I can access it from a browser tab being server by HTTPS.

I don't want to deal with certificates, and want to keep the code on the socket.io server mostly the same, so I want to proxy the IP for the server via Cloudflare and establish SSL like that.

But I haven't been able to, the socket.io server uses no other webserver, but I can change it to use the native NodeJS `http` or `https` libraries.

But I haven't been able to access the socket.io server via the Cloudflare proxy. Clouflare returns 522 errors, which means a connection timeout.

Comment: its something else other than Cloudflare or https, maybe you hardcoded `http://` somewhere, maybe CORS. Errors? Code?

Comment: There's no way you do https and not deal with certificates.  A certificate is required on the listening server for https.

Comment: @jfriend00 This is not true... Cloudflare's flexible SSL mode allows the connection between your server and cloudflare to go unencrypted.

Comment: @ReinF - Well, there IS a certificate somewhere.  Maybe cloudfare is managing it for you.  There is no such thing as an https endpoint that doesn't use a certificate.

Comment: @jfriend00, well you see the way Cloudflare works is Cloudflare acts as a proxy, Cloudflare uses a valid SSL certificate between the user and Cloudflare, but the connection between Cloudflare and your server doesn't have to use any certificate.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Alright so it seems like the issue was indeed CORS related, but now I am stuck wondering if I can add the right response headers without adding express as a dependency.

Comment: my bad yeah Cloudflare is obvious 443 :(, what I do without issues is `client -> cloudflare:443 -> nginx:80 -> app:8080`, ideally you want your app to always be on 80 or 443 cloudflare or not

Answer (score 0):

Apparantly flexible SSL only works with with ports 443->80

Other ports are not supported...